# URL Rewriting

Tags: asp.net, url, mapping

i am using URL rewriting in my asp.net application using regx

virtual URL is

```
/ProductDatabaseCMS/(?<category>\w*)/Product/(?<product>\w*)\.aspx
```

original URL is

```
/ProductDatabaseCMS/Product.aspx?PROD_ID=${product}
```

application path is `~/ProductDatabaseCMS`

my application has master page that uses style sheet and the path is

```
~/App_Themes/Styles/Style_Sheet.css
```

i am requesting the URL

```
/ProductDatabaseCMS/(?<category>\w*)/Product/(?<product>\w*)\.aspx
```

from one of the webpage of application using  Hyperlink control but in that case stylesheet is not working for this page Because it is taking path

```
~/ProductDatabaseCMS/(?<category>\w*)/Product/App_Themes/Styles/Style_Sheet.css
```

what i have to do in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a relative URI to reference the external stylesheet, you have to consider this: Relative URIs are always resolved from a base URI which is the URI of the current resource if not declared otherwise.

So if you request `/foo/bar` and there is a relative URI reference `css/baz.css` in the HTML document, it would be resolved to `/foo/css/baz.css` as `/foo/bar` is the base URI.

To solve this problem you have two options:

1. use absolute URIs or at least absolute paths to reference the resources (e.g. `/App_Themes/Styles/Style_Sheet.css`), or
2. set a suitable base URI using the `BASE` HTML element (e.g. `<base href="/">`) so that every relative URI is resolved from that new base URI.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ["root-relative path"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22root+relative%22+path) for the CSS href. You start the href with "/", that's all.

Try: `/App_Themes/Styles/Style_Sheet.css`