# Drupal-like clean URL system

Tags: php, html, url, drupal

I've been hired to re-factor some homemade websites. Those websites are made in the good old fashion way: one page = one php file with header, content, script, footer. Now my client wants to update the layout of all the pages I feel like DRYing a bit the code by creating a clean URL system. Instead of :

```
example.com/page1.php, example.com/page2.php
```

I'd like to have:

```
example.com/page1, example.com/page2
```

Where the two pages call the same php file just charging the content of the page.

My questions are: 1. how to catch the URL and converts it into parameters? 2. how to avoid the website default behavior to search in directory /page1 or /page2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL Rewriting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556240/url-rewriting)

Comment: Also note that this may impact indexing in search engines (SEO)

Comment: Ever heard of `.htaccess` (especially `mod_rewrite`) for `apache` or the config files for `nginx`? You should read about them! They are just amazing!

Comment: I think, a better duplicate is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php. Thanks for your comments and help. @TiMESPLiNTER I appreciate the direction your pointing but your tone hurts me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Apache web server, you can read-up on Multiviews. While normally used to serve up the same page in different languages, its effect is that whenever you specify a name without an extension, and that name isn't already a folder, then the file with the same name will be served.

For example, you ask for `http://localhost/example`, and `example` isn't a folder name, then if `example.php` exists, it will be served up instead. You just have to make sure you don't have two or more files with the same name and different extensions, or a folder and file with the same name.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure that I can use the behavior this time. But it's good to know!