# Url rewriting in classic asp

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, asp-classic

How can i rewrite  home/search.asp?search=biscuits to  home/?q=biscuits

I used this format,but not able to pass ?in url

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
     <rewrite>
       <rules>
         <rule name="Search">
           <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/?$" />       
           <action type="Rewrite" url="search.asp?search={R:1}" />
         </rule>
       </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: There's quite a lot of stuff on SO about this. Perhaps you can find a clue just by looking at the [OP for this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556240/url-rewriting).

Comment: First things to check - are you using IIS 7 or above, and do you actually have the url rewrite module installed?